# wifi is not connecting after Virtual box installation in windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, virtualbox

I installed virtual box in windows 8 32 bit through my wifi connection.

After i started virtualbox, my system  is still connected to wifi, but not accessing to internet, it is recieving no bytes but sending data, when i diagnosize my connection , it shows the problem with wireless adapter,  it is showing "server not found" error in firefox. When i restart my system , wifi is working normally. and in wireless properties it is connected to virtualbox host, i did disable it, but still not working. what to do ,help me out.

can any one please help me out. I am struggling for this for 5 days.

Comment: win-key + R, type cmd, type ipconfig, press enter. What does it say under each adapter for the ip address and gateway?

Comment: @Voora Tarun, you said it works after restart, so when does it actually stop ?